# How do I filter and then calculate the mean using the pipe operator?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter a dataframe and then calculate the mean of a column. But I want to use the pipe operator, and I'm not sure how I can do that.

The dataframe name is `vocab`, and the year I am filtering on is `2016`. The name of the column I want to calculate the mean of is `education`.

```
vocab %>%
  filter(year == 2016) %>%
  mean(vocab$education)
```

Am I mixing up dplyr and base r syntax here? Must I only use dplyr syntax with pipe operators?

Comment: Get means for each year with `group_by(year)` then `summarise()`. See `?summarise` for the syntax.

Comment: When you use the pipe `%>%`, the object on the left side of the pipe gets passed as the first argument to the function on the right side. So you do not need to include `vocab` again in `filter()`, it should just be `filter(year == 2016)`

Comment: Ok thanks, I changed it. But for some reason, it still does not work? I'm used to doing mean(vocab$education), but I don't know how to use that syntax with the pipe method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do either of those:

```
vocab %>%
  filter(year == 2016) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(education), mean)

vocab %>%
  filter(year == 2016) %>%
  summarize_at("education", mean)

vocab %>%
  filter(year == 2016) %>%
  summarize(education = mean(education))

vocab %>%
  filter(year == 2016) %>%
  pull(education) %>%
  mean
```

The problem is not so much about mixing syntax, but really more about understanding what you are doing, the pipe feeds its left side to the first argument of the function on the right side, so your try means :

```
  mean(vocab %>% filter(year == 2016), vocab$education)
  # or 
  mean(filter(vocab, year == 2016), vocab$education)
```

which doesn't make sense.

That being said, in practice you don't see a lot of `$` being used in pipe chain because other options fit more nicely with the syntax, and `$` does partial matching, which is not the kind of things that the `tidyverse` team likes much.